# What is the point of a "plain" begin-end block?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm reading some third party Verilog, and found this:

```
function [31:0] factorial;
    input [3:0] operand;
    reg [3:0] index;

    begin
        factorial = operand ? 1 : 0;
        for(index = 2; index <= operand; index = index + 1)
        factorial = index * factorial;
    end
endfunction
```

It seems that the `begin` and `end` keywords are redundant here. Are they? What is their use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about the general case, but in this specific case:

> If a function contains more than one statement, the statements must be
> enclosed in a begin-end or fork-join block.

Source: [Verilog Golden Reference Guide](http://www.fpga.com.cn/hdl/training/verilog%20reference%20guide.pdf)

Comment: `begin/end` is no longer required for a `function` or `task` with multiple statements in SystemVerilog. See other answers.

Answer (score 8):

Both answers are correct. If the Verilog task or function had multiple statements, they were also required to have begin-end statements. Starting in SystemVerilog-2005, we removed the requirement to put begin-end inside of something that already had a begin-end. Most of us on the committee thought it was silly to require a begin-end inside of something that was already going to have endfunction/endtask. I mean, come-on! Don't you think a compiler could figure out that when it got the endtask/endfunction statement that it was at the end of the task or function?? Removing the begin-end from tasks and functions cuts out a surprising amount of useless code. Score another point for SystemVerilog!

Answer (score 1):

According to the SystemVerilog extension (IEEE Standard 1800-2009), the `begin/end` keywords are optional inside a `function`.  However, your toolset (simulator, etc.) must be capable of understanding this syntax, which was introduced in 2005.